# Recommended tool for transliterating image text to English

Tags: перевод

I've stumbled across [an excellent future](http://zolotarevdesign.com/roman-legion) that is only labelled in Russian and am wondering whether there are good tools for taking Russian text — as an image — and transliterating it.

[image]

(From context I think I can get from there to an understanding of most of the contents.)

Comment: what a point in transliterating texts without translation ? Not names, titles, but the text? you can use some OCR program to get text from the picture ( FineReader, CuneiForm, Teserract, etc ).

Comment: @Arioch The value of transliteration alone falls off a bit as one gets down in the text, but I can't determine where in advance so — well, you get the idea. Actually think about things bit and they become clear!

Answer (score 1):

Do it yourself. [There's a site](http://www.newocr.com/) for free online OCR (Optical Character recognition). What you have to do is:

1. [From that site](http://zolotarevdesign.com/roman-legion), save the pictures on your computer. I mean the big ones, the halves, not the one you posted here in your question.
2. Choose the first half picture on the OCR site, choose Russian as the text language, and press the "Upload + OCR" button there.
3. With their Select tool choose an area with the text and press the "OCR" button.
4. Below the image, read the Russian text which you can copy and paste into a translator.

UPD.: To transliterate a Russian text with the Latin alphabet, copy the Russian text, go to [this site](http://translit.net/), paste the text into the central big field and press "В транслит" above the field.